# Microsoft excel : Cell updated history

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have excel sheet which was created on 01.01.2017 . i would like to know the timing when each cell has been created/modified. Excel sheet contain 300 rows, 15 columns and track change has not been enabled.

Comment: Is the workbook on a drive with automatic backups?  You might be able to go through each previous version of the workbook and see what is different from version to version.

Comment: Thank for reply. The workbook is not on shared drive and kept in standalone PC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the **Protect and Share Workbook** Function in the tap **Review** can be something for you.

[image]

After that you click on **Track Changes**

[image]

And then you can say what you want to see!

[image]

After that you can see thechanges on the cell with the History.

[image]